# Compose Android Activity before Displaying

Tags: android, android-activity

When I create an Activity I am passing some parameters to it with Intent extras.  I put some of these variables in the view of the activity ie; TextView, WebView etc.  When the Activity pops up on the screen it is first blank then composes the screen and displays properly a fraction of a second later.  This gets exaggerated when using custom animation to bring in the new activity, it slides in completely empty then displays the data when stopped.  How do I wait for the Activity to be live before displaying anything?

> Here is some of my code:

```
public void sendOrderComplete(String result) { 
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowOrderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("order_id", txtorderid.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra("web_results", result);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

Comment: wait for activity onStart()

Comment: can you elaborate please?